# Blockchain.info keeps sending wallet backups

Tags: blockchain.info

Blockchain.info is sending my wallet backups over and over again;
is this someone trying to hack my wallet or something else?

I haven't done anything on my account, no settings changed et cetera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard if you have *backup wallet* chosen in your settings. Alternatively, email backups will send a `wallet.aes.json` file to your specified email address. A few things to keep in mind:

- The `aes` part means your wallet is encrypted using your Blockchain login (and secondary password). If your password is changed then your newer wallet files can only be decrypted using the new passwords
- The `json` part means the decrypted `aes` is a readable `json` format which can be read by humans and imported by various programs
- Changing your password will change your decryption mnemonic.

The backup `wallet.aes.json` files are good for recovering old wallets but if your BTC has been moved from those addresses it does not recover your money.